# Determine the volume of a solid in space

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, volume

I'm trying to determine the volume of the solid defined by the following inequalities

$$ [(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}: x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4 , x \geq 0 , z \leq 1] $$

So I tried to integrate with respect to $z$ first and then used polar coordinates for $xy$:

$$ \iint \left( \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^1 1 dz \right) dxdy = \iint 1 - \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} dxdy =$$
$$ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{2} r(1-\sqrt{4-r^2}) dxdy = ... = \frac{14\pi}{3} $$

Which I think is wrong! Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with spherical coordinates? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: Replace $\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^1 1 dz$ by $\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^{\min\left(1,\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\right)}1 dz.$

Answer (score 1):

You might want to approach it using [spherical coordinates](https://mathinsight.org/spherical_coordinates) by computing the integral:

$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{\sin^{-1}(1/2)}\int_0^{1/\cos\phi}\rho^2sin\phi \quad d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty clear to me that the restriction on $x$ just cuts the volume in half, which can be calculated by integrating cylinders

$$V = \frac \pi 2 \int_{-2}^1(4-z^2) dz =  \frac \pi 2 \bigg [  (4)(3)-\frac 13(1-(-8)) \bigg]  = \frac{9\pi}2$$

Comment: How did $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4$ become $4-z^2$? i.e should I integrate with respect to x and y first?

Comment: I am integrating infinitesimal cylinders parallel to the x-y plane, having height = $dz$,  radius $r = \sqrt{4-z^2}$ and  volume...
$$dV = \pi r^2 dz  = \pi(4-z^2)dz$$
The x and y integration has already been done to arrive at the formula $\pi r^2$ for the area inside a circle